# mysqlrouter not listen to port 6446 R/W

Tags: mysql-innodb-cluster, mysqlrouter

i install on 3 vm ubuntu22 innodbcluster and it works fine here the result of

```
cluster.status()
{
"clusterName": "medhitcluster",
"defaultReplicaSet": {
"name": "default",
"primary": "inno1:3306",
"ssl": "DISABLED",
"status": "OK",
"statusText": "Cluster is ONLINE and can tolerate up to ONE failure.",
"topology": {
"inno1:3306": {
"address": "inno1:3306",
"memberRole": "PRIMARY",
"mode": "R/W",
"readReplicas": {},
"replicationLag": "applier_queue_applied",
"role": "HA",
"status": "ONLINE",
"version": "8.3.0"
},
"inno2:3306": {
"address": "inno2:3306",
"memberRole": "SECONDARY",
"mode": "R/O",
"readReplicas": {},
"replicationLag": "applier_queue_applied",
"role": "HA",
"status": "ONLINE",
"version": "8.3.0"
},
"inno3:3306": {
"address": "inno3:3306",
"memberRole": "SECONDARY",
"mode": "R/O",
"readReplicas": {},
"replicationLag": "applier_queue_applied",
"role": "HA",
"status": "ONLINE",
"version": "8.3.0"
}
},
"topologyMode": "Single-Primary"
},
"groupInformationSourceMember": "inno1:3306"
###############################################################
```

but after i bootstarp router on a different vm using:
mysqlrouter --ssl-mode=disabled --bootstrap root@inno1 --directory /etc/mysqlrouter --user=root --account=router1

it listen only on RO ports 6447,6449,8443.

here the log of mysqlrouter please help me:

```
root@inno2:~# tail -80 /etc/mysqlrouter/log/mysqlrouter.log
2024-02-23 14:21:32 main SYSTEM [7fd6775b9d80] Starting 'MySQL Router', version: 8.0.36 ((Ubuntu))
2024-02-23 14:21:32 io INFO [7fd6775b9d80] starting 4 io-threads, using backend 'linux_epoll'
2024-02-23 14:21:32 http_server INFO [7fd6775b9d80] listening on 0.0.0.0:8443
2024-02-23 14:21:32 metadata_cache_plugin INFO [7fd65dffb640] Starting Metadata Cache
2024-02-23 14:21:32 metadata_cache INFO [7fd65dffb640] Connections using ssl_mode 'disabled'
2024-02-23 14:21:32 metadata_cache INFO [7fd674457640] Starting metadata cache refresh thread
2024-02-23 14:21:32 metadata_cache INFO [7fd674457640] Connected with metadata server running on inno1:3306
2024-02-23 14:21:32 routing INFO [7fd64dffb640] [routing:bootstrap_ro] started: routing strategy = round-robin-with-fallback
2024-02-23 14:21:32 routing INFO [7fd64dffb640] Start accepting connections for routing routing:bootstrap_ro listening on '0.0.0.0:6447'
2024-02-23 14:21:32 routing INFO [7fd64d7fa640] [routing:bootstrap_rw] started: routing strategy = first-available
2024-02-23 14:21:32 routing INFO [7fd64d7fa640] Start accepting connections for routing routing:bootstrap_rw listening on '0.0.0.0:6446'
2024-02-23 14:21:32 routing INFO [7fd64cff9640] [routing:bootstrap_x_ro] started: routing strategy = round-robin-with-fallback
2024-02-23 14:21:32 routing INFO [7fd64cff9640] Start accepting connections for routing routing:bootstrap_x_ro listening on '0.0.0.0:6449'
2024-02-23 14:21:32 routing INFO [7fd647fff640] [routing:bootstrap_x_rw] started: routing strategy = first-available
2024-02-23 14:21:32 routing INFO [7fd647fff640] Start accepting connections for routing routing:bootstrap_x_rw listening on '0.0.0.0:6448'
2024-02-23 14:21:32 metadata_cache INFO [7fd674457640] Potential changes detected in cluster after metadata refresh (view_id=0)
2024-02-23 14:21:32 metadata_cache INFO [7fd674457640] Metadata for cluster 'medhitcluster' has 3 member(s), single-primary:
2024-02-23 14:21:32 metadata_cache INFO [7fd674457640] inno1:3306 / 33060 - mode=RO
2024-02-23 14:21:32 metadata_cache INFO [7fd674457640] inno2:3306 / 33060 - mode=RO
2024-02-23 14:21:32 metadata_cache INFO [7fd674457640] inno3:3306 / 33060 - mode=RO
2024-02-23 14:21:32 routing INFO [7fd674457640] Stop accepting connections for routing routing:bootstrap_x_rw listening on 0.0.0.0:6448
2024-02-23 14:21:32 routing INFO [7fd674457640] Stop accepting connections for routing routing:bootstrap_rw listening on 0.0.0.0:6446
```